# Upload csv file and get datas php

Tags: php, csv, file-upload, utf-8

I am working on a website where there is an upload of a csv file on the server then we get this file to retrieve the data and make database insertions. The content of the csv file contains UTF8 accents (for example 'Cédric')
With the current code, when we browse the file, Cédric becomes Cdric and if I open the uploaded file in Excel, it is well written Cédric

Here is the form code

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
                      <label>File</label>
                      <input id="upload" name="upload" type="file" value="">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the upload function

```
            if (isset($_FILES['upload']) && $_FILES['upload']['error'] == 0) {
            $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if (strtolower($extension) !== 'csv') {
                $error['msg'] = 'Error';
            }

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], 'upload/' . $_FILES['upload']['name']))) {
                $error['msg'] = 'OK !';
            }
        }
```

And the data recovery code

```
$files = file('upload/' . $inputFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach (array_slice($files, 1, 5000) as $datas){
  $data = explode(';', $datas);
  var_dump($data[0]);
  die();
}
```

The var_dump($data[0]); show "Cdric"

How to do this to have "Cédric" please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the correct header information before print UTF

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$files = file('upload/' . $inputFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach (array_slice($files, 1, 5000) as $datas){
  $data = explode(';', $datas);
  echo $data[0];
  die();
}
```

Comment: If I did this, I have 'C dric'

Comment: Try just echo ($data[0]); without utf8_encode

Comment: I have 'C�dric'

Comment: Are you sure that your csv it's UTF-8 encoded ?

Comment: yes I create the file to upload with excel and save it as CSV UTF-8

Comment: try save csv file with notepad++ and select format>UTF-8

Comment: Same thing, I think it's when I save the file on server no?

Comment: when I opened the file in /upload in phpstorm the encoding is UTF-8 but in file I have � and PHPStorm said "Files was loaded in the wrong encoding: 'UTF-8'"

Comment: Try to upload with filezilla. Maybe phpstorm change your encoding